# Eliminate the parameters to find a Cartesian equation of the curve and sketch the curve. $x = e^t – 1, y = e^{2t}$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Eliminate the parameters to find a Cartesian equation of the curve and sketch the curve.

$x = e^t – 1, y = e^{2t}$.

My attempt:

$x = e^{t} - 1$

$x + 1 = e^{t}$

$\ln(x+1) = t$

so

$y = e^{2t} = e^{2\ln(x+1)} = (x+1)^2$ [fixed mistake]

I think I eliminated the parameters now how would I sketch this?

I made a table

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
t& 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
x & 0& e^{1}-1 & e^{2} - 1 & e^{3}-1 & e^{4}-1\\ \hline
y & 1 & e^{2} & e^{4} & e^{6} & e^{8}\\ \hline
\end{array}

If I graph above with respect to x and y, then would this be correct?

Comment: The last equality is wrong: $\;\mathrm e^{2\ln a}=\bigl(\mathrm e^{\ln a}\bigr)^2=a^2$.

Comment: Do I just sketch the $y=(x+1)^2$ function?

Comment: Not quite, because , as you can see $\mathrm e^t -1>-1$.

Answer (score 2):

As you were told in the comments, there is an error in your computations and the answer is $y=e^{2\ln(x+1)}=\left(e^{\ln(x+1)}\right)^2=(x+1)^2$. But there is an even shorter path to that conclusion: since $x+1=e^t$, then $y=e^{2t}=(e^t)^2=(x+1)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

How you would sketch this:

Hint 1: Note that $x$ can take on each possible value in precisely the set $(-1,\infty)$ as $t$ varies over the reals.